# Random libx11 hangs

Tags: c, x11, xcb

My application is randomly hanging when calling **libX11** functions. For example: calling `XGetClassHint`, `XGetWindowProperty` or `XListInputDevices` sometimes do not return.

For example, here is a backtrace when calling `XGetClassHint`

```
#0  0xb70a762c in poll () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0xb6f980f0 in _xcb_conn_wait (c=0x9d66a20, cond=0xbf98c600, vector=0x0, count=0x0) at ../../src/xcb_conn.c:316
#2  0xb6f9a7e1 in xcb_wait_for_reply (c=0x9d66a20, request=178, e=0xbf98c68c) at ../../src/xcb_in.c:395
#3  0xb7597746 in _XReply (dpy=0x9d660d8, rep=0xbf98c6f0, extra=0, discard=0) at ../../src/xcb_io.c:462
#4  0xb75750a0 in XGetWindowProperty (dpy=0x9d660d8, w=31457802, property=67, offset=0, length=8192, delete=0, req_type=31, actual_type=0xbf98c78c, actual_format=0xbf98c788, nitems=0xbf98c784, bytesafter=0xbf98c780, prop=0xbf98c77c) at ../../src/GetProp.c:70
#5  0xb7573f51 in XGetClassHint (dpy=0x9d660d8, w=31457802, classhint=0xbf98c83c) at ../../src/GetHints.c:312
#6  0x080ccfac in WindowManager::get_class (this=0x8144460, window=@0xbf98c814, clase=0xbf98c83c) at src/WindowManager.cpp:1334
```

I've traced the X11 messages between my application and the server and I'm receiving the reply to the GetProperty requesting `WM_CLASS`:

```
001:<:00b2: 24: Request(20): GetProperty delete=false(0x00) window=0x01e0020a property=0x43("WM_CLASS") type=0x1f("STRING") long-offset=0x00000000 long-length=0x00002000
001:>:00b2:52: Reply to GetProperty: type=0x1f("STRING") bytes-after=0x00000000 data='Navigator\000Iceweasel\000'
```

My application is single threaded and I can see is still receiving and processing X11 messages from the server, but it looks that it never returns from `XGetClassHint` because for some reason didn't processed the GetProperty reply.

The OS I'm using is a standard **debian squeeze**, and the relevant packages are:

```
ii  libx11-6                                            2:1.3.3-4+squeeze1               X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-6-dbg                                        2:1.3.3-4+squeeze1               X11 client-side library (debug package)
ii  libx11-data                                         2:1.3.3-4+squeeze1               X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-dev                                          2:1.3.3-4+squeeze1               X11 client-side library (development headers)
ii  libx11-xcb1                                         2:1.3.3-4+squeeze1               Xlib/XCB interface library
ii  libx11-xcb1-dbg                                     2:1.3.3-4+squeeze1               Xlib/XCB interface library (debug package)
ii  libxcb1                                             1.6-1+squeeze1                   X C Binding
ii  libxcb1-dbg                                         1.6-1+squeeze1                   X C Binding, debugging symbols
ii  libxcb1-dev                                         1.6-1+squeeze1                   X C Binding, development files
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks!

**Update**

After some more debugging it seems that this problem was happening when a SIGCHLD was being handled by the program. In the signal handler I was just writing to a pipe to notify the main thread, but not doing any operation with libX11. But in the end removing the signal handler made the problem disappear. Does it make sense? or can I expect this problem to appear again in the future?

Thanks again

Comment: Can you build against native Xlib instead of XlibXcb?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure how to do this using the debian packages. Uninstalling libx11-xcb would probably work but I need that dependency for other stuff I'm using

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with XlibXcb but I'm pretty sure you don't need to uninstall anything. You just link your application with `-lX11` instead of `-lx11-xcb1` or whatever. This won't necessarily work. Well, I'm almost sure it won't work, but it *just* might work, which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either because you're doing something in the `SIGCHLD` handler (or as result of) that you're not supposed to or less likely because Xcb isn't handling an `EINTR` error correctly.

My guess is that `SIGCHLD` is delivered to a thread (which I'll call the reaper thread) while it's in the middle of a call to Xcb. The handler then writes to the pipe, which blocks because the pipe buffer is full. The reaper thread is now holding an Xcb lock while waiting for the pipe to drain. The main thread that's supposed to be reading the pipe then makes an call to Xcb, which tries to acquire the lock that the reaper thread is holding. Since the reaper thread is blocked waiting for the main thread to read the pipe and the main thread is blocked waiting for the reaper thread to release the Xcb lock you get a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I understand well what you're saying, I think that's not the problem I'm having. I don't see the main thread locked (in the sense of trying to get hold of a lock already hold by the reaper thread). In fact, the main thread reads from the pipe successfully and continues reading X11 messages from the server but it's blocked because for some reason it *misses* the correct reply to the request so the Xlib method never returns

Comment: I just noticed that you said your application was single threaded, but in your update you say the SIGCHLD handler notifies the main thread, suggesting that it's running in another thread. Have you created another thread to handle SIGCHLD (or to do anything else) or is your application truly single-threaded?

Comment: Yes sorry. It's single threaded and in the SIGCHLD handler I'm writing to a non blocking unix socket. Later on when the signal handler exits the select in the program will 'wake up' and read the data sent from the signal handler. I hope it makes sense to you